# Python command line arguments - hope to print error when no argument

Tags: python

I have a following simple code:

```
import sys, getopt

ifile=''
ofile=''

try:
    opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:],"h:i:o:")
except getopt.GetoptError as e:
    print (str(e))
    print("test.py -i input -o output")
    sys.exit(2)

for o, a in opts:
    if o == '-h':
       print 'test.py -i input -o output'
       sys.exit()
    elif o == '-i':
       ifile=a
    elif o == '-o':
       ofile=a
```

What should I need to add, if I want to print error (and also help) message 'test.py -i input -o output' when I execute just the script like:

```
$ python test.py
```

Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can write

```
if len(sys.argv) <= 1:
    print('test.py -i input -o output')
    exit(1)
```

after the imports, which basically means that if i don't have any arguments, print the message and quit running the script.

Comment: Thanks. that lines should be under the if loop for opts, right?

Comment: Putting it just below `import sys, getopt` would be better in my opinion.

Answer (score 5):

Just as an alternative, if you are interested, the documentation for getopts actually provides a suggestion to use argparse, which significantly reduces the lines of code you have to write to handle arguments.

Look at the bottom of the doc here:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/getopt.html#getopt.GetoptError

And here is the documentation for `argparse`

https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#module-argparse

The big bonus with `argparse` is that has a built in "help" that is nicely formatted. Look at the following example. You can take this code and test on your end too.

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser, RawTextHelpFormatter

parser = ArgumentParser(
    description='This application will perform actions',
    formatter_class=RawTextHelpFormatter
)

parser.add_argument(
    '-i',
    help='Things with i',
)

parser.add_argument(
    '-o',
    help='Things with o',
)

args = vars(parser.parse_args())

if args.get('i'):
    print(args.get('i'))
elif args.get('o'):
    print(args.get('o'))
else:
    parser.error('Invalid options provided')
```

Just thought I'd share as an alternative.